# Частотный анализ текста c++

Tags: c++

Решил я написать частотный анализ текста на `c++`.
Возникли следующие проблемы:
Русские символы нужны на всех платформах(`linux`, `mac os`, `windows`), поэтому хотел работать с данными, которые "могут всё".

Класс `analisys`:

```
#define rus_size 33 * 2
#define eng_size 26 * 2
#define rus_space_size 33 * 2 + 1
#define eng_space_size 26 * 2 + 1

class analysis {
private:
    std::wstring rus_alphabet[rus_size];
    std::wstring eng_alphabet[eng_size];
    std::wstring rus_alphabet_space[rus_space_size];
    std::wstring eng_alphabet_space[eng_space_size];
    int _indexOfSymbol(std::wstring const &, std::wstring[], int);
    int _indexOfSymbol(wchar_t, std::wstring[], int);
    int _indexOfMaxElement(int*, int);
public:
    analysis();
    void showAlphabet();
    void showAlphabet(std::wstring const &, bool);
    std::wstring analisys(std::wstring const &, std::wstring const &, bool);
};
```

Код алфавитов(русский и английский), конструктор класса:

```
this->rus_alphabet[0] = L"А";
this->rus_alphabet[1] = L"Б";
this->rus_alphabet[2] = L"В";
this->rus_alphabet[3] = L"Г";
this->rus_alphabet[4] = L"Д";
this->rus_alphabet[5] = L"Е";
и т.д.
```

Такая же история и для английского алфавита.
Затем основные действия:

```
std::wstring analysis::analisys(std::wstring const & text, std::wstring const & lang_of_text, bool space) {

std::wstring result = L"";

if(lang_of_text == L"rus"){
    if(space){
        int count_of_symbols[rus_space_size];
    }
    else{
        int count_of_symbols[rus_size];

        // Новый массив
        for (int k = 0; k < rus_size; ++k) {
            count_of_symbols[k] = 0;
        }

        // Считаем сколько раз повторяется каждый символ в тексте
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); ++i) {
            if(iswalpha(rus_alphabet[_indexOfSymbol(std::to_wstring(text[i]), rus_alphabet, rus_size)][0])) {
                count_of_symbols[_indexOfSymbol(std::to_wstring(text[i]), rus_alphabet, rus_size)] += 1;
            }
        }

        // По убыванию даем информацию о кол-ве найденных символов
        for (int j = 0; j < rus_size; ++j) {
            int max = _indexOfMaxElement(count_of_symbols, rus_size);
            result = result + rus_alphabet[max] + L" – " + std::to_wstring(count_of_symbols[max]) + L"\n";
            count_of_symbols[max] = -1;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

return NULL;
}
```

Функции _indexOfSymbol(две перегрузки):

```
int analysis::_indexOfSymbol(wchar_t symbol, std::wstring alphabet[], int size) {

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if(std::to_wstring(symbol) == alphabet[i]) return i;
}

return NULL;
}
```

Вторая перегрузка:

```
int analysis::_indexOfSymbol(std::wstring const & symbol, std::wstring alphabet[], int size) {

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if(symbol == alphabet[i]) return i;
}

return NULL;
}
```

И функция поиска _indexOfMaxElement:

```
int analysis::_indexOfMaxElement(int* array, int size) {
int index_max = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if(array[index_max] < array[i]) index_max = i;
}

return index_max;
}
```

В основной программе main.cpp вызов выглядит так:

```
analysis _analysis;

wstring kek;

getline(wcin, kek);

wcout << _analysis.analisys(kek, L"rus", false);
```

Проблема в том, что он отказывается искать символы/сравнивать символы/еще что-то делать с символами. 
На выходе должно быть примерно следующее:

```
A - 7;
Б - 5;
Я - 4;
Д - 3;
```

и т.д. по убыванию.

Но у меня на выходе все по нулям. Я ставил точки останова и вот некоторые данные с них:

```
Текст который я ввёл - L"Ð\U0000009fÑ\U00000080Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ\U00000082 ÐºÐ¾Ð´" (по идее должно быть - "Привет код")
В цикле, который считает символы, у меня ни разу не выполняется условие.
```

Как это поправить?

Comment: В main setlocale сделали? И проверьте, что русские буквы нормально читаются (т.е. локаль в системе правильно установлена)

Comment: Что за `getline`? Читайте через `std::cin`, раз уж всюду c++.

Comment: @arrowd как бы для строк cin не робит, т.к. он считывает криво.

Comment: @avp а вот не поставил. Ой ой, сейчас сделаю

Comment: @avp поставил локаль, не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла замена кодировки с `utf-8` на `windows-1251`.